# Android error: savedInstanceState cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I'm writing a simple calculator app for Android but get the error "savedInstanceState cannot be resolved to a variable" at the end of the "onCreate" method. Any suggestions how to get rid of this error?

My code looks as follows:

```
package se.robert.kalkylator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

public class kalkylatorActivity extends Activity {
 public EditText text;
 private Button addButton;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displayarea);

 }

 // This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
 // "On Click property" of the button
 public void myClickHandler(View view) {
  switch (view.getId()) {
  case R.id.add:

//   text.setText("Add!");


   break;
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Did you save your file? Is this actually your code?

Comment: What have you set as your "Project Build Target" (Right-click on Project Name in Eclipse, Properties, Android). Are you sure that your SDK installation is working as it should (i.e. have you successfully tested other sample projects)? Have you set the SDK-path in Eclipse (Window, Preferences, Android)?

Answer (score 0):

```
package se.robert.kalkylator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;

public class kalkylatorActivity extends Activity 
{
   public EditText text;
   private Button addButton;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displayarea);



        public void myClickHandler(View view) 
        {
           switch (view.getId()) 
          {
           case R.id.add:

           //   text.setText("Add!");


            break;
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate your answer by adding explaination of what you did and how it helped to solve the problem.

Comment: Put the myClickHandler() method inside the oncreate() method